# saving dictionary to CSV file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I'm trying write the data to the file currencies.csv using this code:
the code for the dictionary is

```
def _fetch_currencies():
     response =urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~vsego/python/currencies.json')
     html = response.read().decode("utf-8")

     currencies = json.loads(html)
     pprint(currencies)

def _save_currencies(currencies):
    with open(('currencies.csv'), 'wt') as my_csv:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter=',')
        csv_writer.writerow(["code","name"])  
        for key,value in currencies.items(): 
            csv_writer.writerow([key,value])

 _save_currencies(_fetch_currencies())
```

when i return the code I get the error message

```
'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items''
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: My Python is a bit rusty, but `_fetch_currencies()` does not return anything. Thus, the call to it should evaluate to `null` or `NoneType` respectively and that's what is handed over to `_save_currencies()`. Since `NoneType` does not have an `items()` method, the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return in `_fetch_currencies()`:

```
def _fetch_currencies():
     response =urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~vsego/python/currencies.json')
     html = response.read().decode("utf-8")
     return json.loads(html) # <- return
```

You don't return any value so by default python returns `None` so when you pass `_fetch_currencies()`  to  `_save_currencies` you are passing `None`.

You can also pass dict.items and call `csv.writerows`:

```
def _save_currencies(currencies):
    with open(('currencies.csv'), 'wt') as my_csv:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter=',')
        csv_writer.writerow(["code","name"])
        csv_writer.writerows(currencies.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are requesting keys from a dictionary that does not have any. The reason is because _fetch_currencies() does not have a return statement.

```
def _fetch_currencies():
     response =urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~vsego/python/currencies.json')
     html = response.read().decode("utf-8")

     currencies = json.loads(html)
     return currencies
```

Regardless, this should work:

```
currencies = {}
for key,value in currencies.items(): 
    print key, value
```

Where this will not work:

```
currencies = None
for key,value in currencies.items(): 
    print key, value
```